# Angular.js get only true keys from object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to only get keys having true value in data object with following format in console:

```
Object {
   Agent=true,
   Analytics / Business Intelligence=true,
   Architecture / Interior Design=false
}
```

I have all these categories in ng-model checkbox input in front end as follows:

```
<li ng-repeat="ai in industry | filter:searchByIndustry" class="checkbox"> 
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="checkboxCategories{{ai.id}}" ng-model="dataCategory[ai.name]" />
    <label class="css-label chrome-style" for="checkboxCategories{{ai.id}}">{{ai.name}}</label>                 
    </label>
</li>
```

Once user check the checkbox the category name has value true on uncheck it becomes false. I want to put true values in string in my angular controller.

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
        return {
            useCat  :$scope.dataCategory
        }
    }, function (value) {

var searchMeta = [];
for( var l in value.useCat ) {
   if (l==true) {
      //code
      searchMeta.push(l)
   }
}
console.log($scope.searchMeta);
}, true );
```

Comment: Firstly, your object declaration is wrong, keys should be in quotes like this `'Analytics / Business Intelligence'`

Comment: Also that object notation is incorrect. Object = { 'Agent': true, } etc

Answer (score 0):

After few attempts following snippet is working:

```
var searchMeta = [];
for( var l in value.useCat ) {
    if(value.useShirts[l]) {
       console.log(l)
       searchMeta.push(l)
    }
    console.log(value.useCat[l])
 }
 console.log(searchMeta);
```

Thanks